# message.react is not a function Duscord.JS

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I want to just make a message reaction, I am using discord.js v12.5.3:

```js
client.on('message', function(msg){
if(msg.content.startsWith('frozen')){
msg.react('️')
}

})
```

the error:

```
msg.react('️')
    ^

TypeError: msg.react is not a function
    at C:\Users\Sans\Desktop\new crow\commands\rolemenu.js:132:5
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

The message don't make a reaction

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please provide code for that entire event `client.on(` need to clearly see how `msg` is defined because as it’s written, that should work.

Comment: okay but `msg` is defined I think

Comment: It says the error is on the 132nd line in your `rolemenu.js` file. It would be interesting to see the rest of the code because (as @Kaspr mentioned) it looks like this part of your code should work.

Comment: Please post your client & intents line. Looks like this: `const client = new Discord.Client()` or something very close to that and should be at the top of your main.js bot file. Also the code around line 132 of your rolemenu.js file as mentioned above.

Comment: @Kaspr intents have no role in this error, the function is on the class prototype and all the Message objects have it unless modified

Comment: @Sansdev please indicate if the answer below resolved your error or not

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your event code to this. Worked for me when I tested it.

```js
client.on('message', async msg => {
    if (msg.content.startsWith('frozen')) {
        msg.react('️')
    }
})
```